# Sending values to web handler [.ashx] from jqueryui dialog box using json ajax

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to send a values entered by customer on jqueryui dialog form to webhandler (ashx) using
ajax post with no success, below is the code:

Webhandler[login.ashx]

```
public class Login : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        // string ID = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];  
        //Want to pass full name , email and selected value of dropdown list 
        // then perform sql query
        string fullname = "";//from ajax
        string email = "";//from ajax
        string scheme = "";//from ajax
        docalculation(fullname, email , scheme);
}

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

            public void docalculation(string name, string email, string scheme)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["umbracoDbDSN"]);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE email = @XX) INSERT INTO dbo.schemeCustomers(CustomerName, CustomerEmail, schemeType, LoginDate) VALUES (@XX,@XX,@XX,@XX)";
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@XX", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@XX", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = scheme;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@XX", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                int result1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
                conn.Close();
                Response.Redirect("/home/schemes.aspx");// response.redirect doesnt works in handler??
            }

}
```

.aspx

```
$('#logintest').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var selectedValue = $('#DropDownList2').val();var fullname = $('#name').val();var email = $('#email').val();
                    var jsonData = '{ "fullname":" + fullname  +", "email": " + email +" , "selectedValue" : " + selectedValue +"}';
                    $.ajax({
                       url: "/login.ashx",

                        type: "POST",
                        data : JSON.stringify({ fullData: jsonData }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.d != "") {
                                alert(response.d);

                            }
                        }


                    });
                });

                 <div id="dialog-form" title="Group Scheme Login">
                <form>
                <fieldset>
                <label for="name">
                    Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                <br />
                <label for="email">
                    Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                <br />
                <select id="DropDownList2">
                    <option value="product1">Camera</option>
                    <option value="product2">DVD</option>
                    <option value="product3">AC</option>
                </select>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
                <br />
                <a href="" id="logintest">Login </a>
                </div>
```

Can anyone assist me on how to pass the parameters to handler, any assistance or suggestion will be highly appreciated , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `HttpContext.Current.Request` in your `ashx` like:

```
 string fullname =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("fullname");
 ...
```

and update your ajax call like this:

```
 var selectedValue = $('#DropDownList2').val(),
     fullname = $('#name').val(),
     email = $('#email').val();

$.ajax({
         url: "/login.ashx",
         type: "POST",
         data : { fullname: fullname, 
                  email:email, 
                  selectedValue:selectedValue },
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) { 
               // do stuff
         }
```

Comment: i tried that but , i get an error :Error Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.Params' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: checked the google chrome console , getting : /login.ashx 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Slap a breakpoint inside the handler,attach to the process, and see what happens if it gets there.

Comment: Oh, then try clicking on the err message in chrome, and check the `response` message. It should tell you the server error.

Comment: thats the test website http://www.myfirth.com/ and if you click on login under the group scheme login section , then u will see the dialog box , there you will see a login action , so when i click on login it should take the customer name and email and selected value .

Comment: f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send
f.extend.ajax
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i

Comment: the current request form is empty

Comment: Oh, try to `JSON.stringify` the values then. Must be the request validation on .NET

Comment: still all the request on handler page is empty :(

Comment: The request leaves the browser with the params populated. Must be something in the ashx. Guess you'll have to do some testing. I assure you this approach works as we use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot add comment into replies as we go on Codrin Eugeniu; just remove

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

and try again. hope it'll work.